# Why moment-timezone returns wrong utcOffset

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

For some timezones results that give `utcOffset` and `moment()` are different, ie for `Europe/Belgrade`. Currently it is `GMT+2`:

```
`Now: ${currentMoment.format()}`
// Now: 2022-06-09T12:12:08+03:00

moment.tz.zone("Europe/Belgrade").utcOffset(moment().unix())
// -60 - wrong, 1hr

moment.tz("Europe/Belgrade").format()
// 2022-06-09T11:07:03+02:00 - correct
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/ecstatic-phoebe-bhcpbl?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 1):

Answer is here https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/989.

Instead of `unix()`

```js
moment.tz.zone("Europe/Belgrade").utcOffset(moment().unix())
```

it is correct to use `valueOf()`

```js
moment.tz.zone("Europe/Belgrade").utcOffset(moment().valueOf())
```